# Getting travel time while performing pgrouting i.e. what are parameters and function required?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, time, function

While doing the pgrouting to find the shortest distance I got success in getting the output but when I thought to come up with the time consumed for travelling, I cannot find the proper source to get the time consumed.

If there is a solution, can you let me know about the function to be used for that in pgrouting?

Comment: You add up the cost of the links returned.

Comment: most functions in pgRouting list (and aggregate) the `cost` column value for each segment traversed, and use that, of course, to determine the most efficient route. e.g. if you pass in the segment length as `cost`, the result will be the 'shortest route', as in 'minimum total length'. sth. like `segment length / max speed` as `cost` would approximate a 'fastest route', returning the 'total minimum travel time'

Comment: I got the minimum travel time successfully but is there any possibility to return both the distance and time spontaneously.